# Migrate existing Firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to migrate the data which already exists in my firebase database: Add a new field to all children; manipulate an existing field (ie a -> a + 3).
Since there is no real frontend available to do that, I wonder how it could be done?

Comment: It's unclear what is meant by migrate the data? Migrate it where? The solution should be pretty straightforward and after  you've spent a little time working with the Firebase API you'll find this can be done in about 30 lines of code or less (Swift)

Comment: i am pretty satisfied with the answer cutiko gave. maybe migrate is a confusing word, but I explained it in detail, even with an example, and obviously cutiko understood exactly what i meant. i don't understand what you mean with too broad... it is a very specific case and surprisingly there is no answer in the web, yet. but as i wrote, i am satisfied ;)

Comment: Glad that answer helped. To me, it's overly complicated as it should be accomplished in about 5 minutes with a small amount of code. It's unclear why you would need HTTP triggers, downloading JSON or utilizing functions - but that's me. To broad because your platform wasn't specified, we don't know how many (or what kind) iterations you would need because we don't know what your structure is. Also, there are no fields in Firebase, just key: value pairs known as parent and child nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no real front end then:

- If the database is small and you are using the RTD then download the JSON and edit it
- If the database is large since you have no front end you should do it with Functions

#### How to do it with Functions

You have to create a Functions project that will have an HTTP request trigger, once you access that url, then the trigger will query the data and for each result will create new data.

For doing this the simplest way to start is following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0). You have to do the same but instead of returning something to the browser with send, just end the Function with a code 200 (if it worked).

I would recommend creating an extra node for verification something like `migration_march: false` and then set it to true once the migration is completed. That way you can avoid unintentional re-migrations. There should be a validation for this once the trigger is started.

Doing a query on Functions is fairly the same as doing it in any other SDK this is the [Functions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

You will probably need to know how to work with promises since your algorithm is gonna be: a query where for each value found set a new value in another place and then move forward to the new value, here is an [illustrative video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=726GW5bg3OY) (couldn't find the original video)

Comment: @Jens sure here to help, remember to mark it as a solution to help others in the same situation when you can confirm it is working